# problem with Single Page Website module

Tags: 7

I wanted to try out the [Single Page Website](https://www.drupal.org/project/single_page_website) module for Drupal 7

I followed the instructions and all seemed to work well, except my anchor links wouldn't work i.e. it wouldn't scroll down the page when I clicked on them.

What might have been the problem there? The only anchor that seemed to work, was the link to a view.

Any ideas where I might have gone wrong or what I might have missed? Any experiences?

Comment: What version of the module are you using? Have you checked the issue queue on drupal.org for similar issues? For example these: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/single_page_website?text=anchor&status=All - this one looks quite similar https://www.drupal.org/node/2278915
This seems maybe like it could be a bug report for a drupal.org module, which would be off topic for this site.

Comment: @cerr Please note that, 'Single page website' module works with Bartik and Zen themes and sub-themes ONLY!

Comment: There is another module out there that doesn't require bartik or zen theme. It is theme independent. https://www.drupal.org/project/single_page_site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue when I was testing out this module as well.

Solution: Create an Alias for each piece of content.

Each node/page you want to include on the single page, visit and add the alias. As admin, visit say, your default page you wish to have at the top, click Edit, and create the alias. In MY experience, once I did this for the pages for the Single Page using the single_page module, it worked.

[image]